# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar 2 fechas con javascript para deshabilitar checkbox?

Tags: javascript, if, fullcalendar

tengo el siguiente código, necesito saber como "NO MOSTRAR" el input de edicion del evento que esta en el segundo modal si la fecha es menor a la de hoy

deben darle doble click a algun elemento con titulo en el calendario y esperar a que les abra el modal de ver/editar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxeditar').click(function() { // este es el modal? no , esto es un checkbox que habilita/deshabilita campos 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      document.getElementById("razondeeliminacion").checked = false
      $('.titulo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.importancia').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.lugar').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.motivo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fuente').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.hora').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fotografo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.descripcion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.tipo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.periodista').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#btsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

    } else {
      $('.titulo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.importancia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.lugar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.motivo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fuente').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.hora').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fotografo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.descripcion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.tipo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.periodista').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

  var date = new Date();
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var dd = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      language: 'es',
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
    },
    defaultDate: yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end) {

      $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        /*
         $('[name="title"]').val(event.title);
         $('[name="lugar"]').val(event.lugar);
                        $('[name="motivo"]').val(event.motivo);
                        $('[name="fuente"]').val(event.fuente);
                        $('[name="tipo"]').val(event.tipo);
                        $('[name="hora"]').val(event.hora);
                        $('[name="fotografo"]').val(event.fotografo);
                        $('[name="descripcion"]').val(event.descripcion);
                        $('[name="reportero"]').val(event.reportero);
                        $('[name="etiquetas"]').val(event.etiquetas);
         */
        var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
        var keys = Object.keys(event);
        while (key = keys.shift()) {
          //console.log(key);
          try {
            var input = form.querySelector('input[name="' + key + '"],select[name="' + key + '"],textarea[name="' + key + '"]');
            console.log(key, event[key], input);
            if (input.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
              var option = input.querySelector('[value="' + event[key] + '"]');
              if (option != null) {
                console.log('selcet====================================');
                //$(input).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                //$(option).attr('selected','selected').click();
                option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                // creo que era haci. :) veamos xD
              }
            } else {
              input.value = event[key];
            }
          } catch (e) {}
        }

        //console.log(event);
      });
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

      edit(event);

    },
    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

      edit(event);

    },
    events: [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 1',
        start: '2018-07-01 07:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-01 09:00:00',
        color: '#beeeef',
        lugar: 'Lugar 1',
        motivo: 'Motivo 1',
        fuente: 'Fuente 1',
        tipo: 'Tipo 1',
        hora: '07:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 1',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 1',
        reportero: 'Reportero 1',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta1',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 1',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 2',
        start: '2018-07-10 09:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-10 11:00:00',
        color: '#ffbbee',
        lugar: 'Lugar 2',
        motivo: 'Motivo 2',
        fuente: 'Fuente 2',
        tipo: 'Tipo 2',
        hora: '09:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 2',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 2',
        reportero: 'Reportero 2',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta2',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 2',
      }
    ]
  });
  //funcion para mover eventos y cambiarlos de fecha
  function edit(event) {
    start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    if (event.end) {
      end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    } else {
      end = start;
    }

    id = event.id;

    Event = [];
    Event[0] = id;
    Event[1] = start;
    Event[2] = end;
    //console.log(event,Event);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'editEventDate.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        Event: Event,
        title: event.title
      },
      success: function(rep) {
        if (rep == 'OK') {
          swal({
            position: 'top-end',
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se ha modificado el dia del evento de forma exitosa',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        } else {
          swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Algo salio mal...',
            html: '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>   04162910634  '
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}
```

```css
.fa-facebook,
.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5998
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #00aced
}

.fa-google-plus,
.fa-google-plus-square {
  color: #dd4b39
}

.fa-youtube,
.fa-youtube-play,
.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000
}

.fa-tumblr,
.fa-tumblr-square {
  color: #32506d
}

.fa-vine {
  color: #00bf8f
}

.fa-flickr {
  color: #ff0084
}

.fa-vimeo-square {
  color: #aad450
}

.fa-pinterest,
.fa-pinterest-square {
  color: #cb2027
}

.fa-linkedin,
.fa-linkedin-square {
  color: #007bb6
}

.fa-instagram {
  #color: #517fa4;
}

.fa-spotify {
  color: #1ED760;
}

#notification-icon {}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/img/imagendefondo.jpg);
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 940px;
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<!-- Page Content -->


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1>Calendario de actividades</h1>
      <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
  <!--notification -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
          <!-- este es para agregar los eventos , mas abajo esta el de editarlos -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo evento
              <div align="center"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-youtube-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-tumblr-square"></span></span>
                <span class="fa fa-3x fa-vimeo-square"></span>
                </span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></span></div>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Debe ser corto" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control" id="fotografo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; TODO EL EQUIPO</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control" id="reportero" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>




          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="hanyerck" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver/Modificar Evento</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control titulo" placeholder="Titulo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control lugar" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control motivo" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control fuente" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control hora" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control fotografo" id="fotografo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; AMBOS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control tipo" id="tipo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control periodista" id="reportero" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control etiquetas" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="razonmodificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la modificacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="razonmodificacion" class="form-control razonmodificacion" id="razonmodificacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la modificacion, si aparece algo aqui fue modificado el evento" required disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" id="razondeeliminacion" hidden="true">
              <label for="razondeeliminacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la eliminacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input name="razondeeliminacion" class="form-control razondeeliminacion" id="razondeeliminacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la eliminacion" disabled pattern=".{15,}" required title="explique con mas de 15 letras por que desea la eliminar el evento"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">Seleccione una opcion <br/>
                  <label class="text-danger"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxeditar" value="checkbox" onclick="activarcasilla(this)"> Editar Evento</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-danger">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
        
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button  id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guardar</button>
         </div>
       </form>
       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
     <!-- FullCalendar -->
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-alpha/locale/es.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esto comprobarías dos Variables de fecha, añadírselo al punto que quieras...

```html
var Fecha1 = new Date(2018,7,1);
var Fecha2 = new Date(2018,7,2);
If (Fecha1 > Fecha2){
  alert("Fecha 1 Mayor que Fecha 2");
}else{
  alert("Fecha 1 Menor que Fecha 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tm = dt => parseInt((new Date(dt).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0)); // date to unix timestamp
var f1 = tm('2018-08-09'); // Fecha 1.
var f2 = tm('2018-08-10'); // Fecha 2.
if(f1 >= f2){
    alert("f1 mayor o igual que f2");
}else{
    alert("f1 menor que f2");
}
```

Comment: Hola Hanyerck, bueno es que hayas respondido, pero lo puedes hacer aún mejor. Te invito a leer [answer]